# How to get name of comma separated id in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using two tables -institute and category. Institute table is having category id with comma separated values like 1,2. I want to get these comma separated values as IT,Health in MySQL query result.

[image]

[image]

I am using this below query:

```
SELECT i.*, c.category_name FROM institute i, category c WHERE FIND_IN_SET(c.category_id, i.institute_category)
```

Which shows me the below result :

[image]

I am looking for comma separated values in categories and dont need duplicate institute id i.e.

[image]

Comment: use group by and then group_concat clauses

Comment: You can use group by clause on institute_id.

Comment: Normalize your database. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: Here is complete description to know what you are doing [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For getting your expected results:

This is what your query will look like (Using `GROUP BY` AND `GROUP_CONCAT`)

```
SELECT i.*, GROUP_CONCAT(c.category_name) FROM institute i, category c 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(c.category_id, i.institute_category) 
GROUP BY i.institute_category
```

Comment: can I apply group_concat and group by more than one column?

Comment: yes you can apply group_concat on multiple columns, but separately

Answer (score 0):

Use `group_concat` function:

```
SELECT i.*, group_concat(c.category_name) FROM institute i, category c
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(c.category_id, i.institute_category)
```